# Rewriting mysql subqueries with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with such structure:

- uid
- sid

all integers. This table simulates friendship between two user.

All I want to do is to find such records that exist only in one direction.

For example:
I want to find number of records that have t1.u_id = 15, when there is no records that have t2.s_id = 15 and t2.u_id = t1.s_id.

So that relationship between two ids exists only once.

It seemed to me that I've managed to write the correct query with subqueries, but then I've started to rewrite the query using left join to increase speed and now...well it's not working.

My query right now is:

```
SELECT * FROM `friends` AS f1 LEFT JOIN `friends` AS f2 
ON f1.user_id = f2.friend_id 
WHERE f1.friend_id=15 AND f2.user_id IS NULL
```

but it's not working. Please help.

NB. I'm using mysql 5, so I can't use EXCEPT statement and all other good things.

Comment: explain *how* it's not working?  records that it finds that it shouldn't or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `friends` AS f1 
    LEFT JOIN `friends` AS f2 ON f1.user_id = f2.friend_id AND f1.friend_id = f2.user_id
WHERE f1.friend_id=15 
    AND f2.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

And this one ?

SELECT * FROM `friends` f1 
LEFT JOIN `friends` f2 ON f1.user_id = f2.friend_id 
WHERE f1.friend_id=15 AND f2.user_id IS NULL

Comment: Guess you found out what the ticks do : )